# FileNotFoundException occurs due to my outputStream method

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

Please bear with me here as I'm new to the site. 
below is a program that I've written for my programming in Java class, and while most of it has gone well so far, I can't seem to get rid of a specific bug.

When the program reaches the third if block (choice == 3) it doesn't let the user enter any data, and if the line

**"outputStream = openOutputTextFile(newerFileName);"**

is present in the if block then a FileNotFoundException occurs. After tinkering around with my code for a while I've found that the error is being thrown because the program cannot find the inputStream anymore. Although I've checked and have found that the program can still find, read, and write to the file that is throwing the error.

I'm thinking that since the error only occurs when I put the outputStream in, and is being thrown by the inputStream, then it probably has something to do with file streams. I just don't know what exactly

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could solve this issue?

```
  public class FileProgram {

    public static PrintWriter openOutputTextFile(String fileName)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintWriter toFile = new PrintWriter(fileName);
        return toFile;
    }

    public static Scanner readFile(String fileName)
    throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        return inputStream;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

        ArrayList<String>fileReader = new ArrayList<String>(10);
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
try {

            System.out.println("Enter the name of the text file you want to copy.");
            String oldFileName = keyboard.nextLine();
            inputStream = readFile(oldFileName);

            while(inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
                String currentLine = inputStream.nextLine();
                fileReader.add(currentLine);
            }

            System.out.println("All data has been collected. Enter the name for the new text file");
            String newFileName = keyboard.nextLine();
            outputStream = openOutputTextFile(newFileName);
            File userFile = new File(newFileName);

            if(userFile.exists())

            {
                System.out.println("The name you entered matches a file that already exists.");
                System.out.println("Here are your options to fix this issue.");
                System.out.println("Option 1: Shut down the program.");
                System.out.println("Option 2: Overwrite the old file with the new empty one.");
                System.out.println("Option 3: Enter a different name for the new file.");
                System.out.println("Enter the number for the option that you want.");
                int choice = keyboard.nextInt();

                if(choice == 1) {
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if(choice == 2) {
                    outputStream = new PrintWriter(newFileName);
                } **else if(choice == 3) {
                    System.out.println("Enter a different name.");
                    String newerFileName = keyboard.nextLine();
                    outputStream = openOutputTextFile(newerFileName);
                }**

            }
            for(int i = 0; i < fileReader.size(); i++) {
                String currentLine = fileReader.get(i);
                outputStream.println(currentLine);
                //System.out.println(currentLine);
            }
            System.out.println("The old file has been copied line-by-line to the new               file.");


        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.out.println("Shutting program down.");
            System.exit(0);

        }

        finally {
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having trouble getting a line of input from your Scanner object after calling .nextInt(). In response to the numeric choice, the user enters an integer followed by a newline.

This line reads the integer from the input buffer:

```
int choice = keyboard.nextInt();
```

However, there's still a newline in the input buffer right after the number. Thus when you call .nextLine():

```
String oldFileName = keyboard.nextLine();
```

You get an empty line. You cannot create a file with an empty string for a file name, so a FileNotFoundException is thrown (this is per spec, see the other answer).

One solution is to consistently use .nextLine(), getting a line at a time from the input buffer. When you need an integer, simply parse the string manually:

```
int choice = Integer.parseInt( keyboard.nextLine() );
```

By the way, in debugging this sort of issue it's very useful to get into the habit of adding some printout statements to see what's going on:

```
public static PrintWriter openOutputTextFile(String fileName)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println( "Trying to create file: '" + fileName + "'" );
    PrintWriter toFile = new PrintWriter(fileName);
    return toFile;
}
```

There are more advanced debugging techniques, but this one is extremely simple, and using it is a lot more effective than using nothing at all.

Comment: I actually use print statements to debug my code already. This is just my first time using File I/O of any sort. I'm off to try your suggestion. Thank you for the help.